# black line/gap in CCParallaxNode backgrounds with cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am using the `CCParallaxNode` to move some sprites and 2 backgrounds-from the same sprite.
all sprites are ok but i have the black line between backgrounds. i have read about this issue.

i have this :

```
back=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mainBack.png"];
back2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mainBack.png"];
```

i add them as child to the CCParallax:

```
[backgroundNode addChild:back z:0 parallaxRatio:bgSpeed positionOffset:ccp(160,240)]; 
        [backgroundNode addChild:back2 z:0 parallaxRatio:bgSpeed positionOffset:ccp(160,720)];
```

and i update them with :

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    CGPoint backgroundScrollVel = ccp(0, -1000);
    backgroundNode.position = ccpAdd(backgroundNode.position, ccpMult(backgroundScrollVel, dt));
```

I have **`tried`** fixing the const in `ccConfig` file to 1, but it didnt help.

I also **`tried`** change the 720 to 719, or 719.5 , but nothing...

still there is the black gap between them.

any suggestion? 
thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

ok.

solved.

what you have to do is to add the image a little bit bigger, with 2 pixels more.
if its 480, add 482 and that will solve it.